# Insert into a table, if there is no such rows

Tags: mysql

I have a sessions table with the 'userid' and 'expired' columns. I want to check, whether any row with the given user ID and not expired exists and insert a new row, if no rows found.

I've read about INSERT IGNORE, but (userid + expired) cannot be a key, since it's possible to have multiple rows with the same users (all expired), I cannot only have more than 1 not expired user.

I tried this, but to no avail ('You have an error...'):

```
IF (SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = :user AND expired = 0) <> 1
INSERT INTO sessions (user) VALUES(:user)
```

('expired' is 0 by default). mySQL version is 5.

**UPDATE**.

I've tried this as well:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0)
    INSERT INTO sessions (user) VALUES(0)
```

using HeidySQL 7. It doesn't work neither. mySQL version is 5.5.

**UPDATE2**. Logical errors in my statement fixed.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my statement is that IF EXISTS is supposed to be in a stored procedure. Nevertheless, the *function* IF() works:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0), 0, 1)
```

Now I'm looking for how to equal plain value like 0 and INSERT INTO statement. This doesn't work:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0), 0,
INSERT INTO sessions (user) VALUES (0) SELECT)
```

If it was C++, I'd say 'type mismatch between ?: operands' and use comma operator. In SQL it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

Well, I've just created a stored routine. Just because I cannot use `IF` otherwise. What a stupid RDBMS this mySQL is!

Answer (score 2):

use `If exists` clause (in this case, `not exists`)

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0)
    INSERT INTO sessions (`user`) VALUES(:user)
```

**edit**

```
    INSERT INTO sessions (`user`) select user from 
    (select :user as user from sessions where not exists(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0)) T1
```

then put 0 or the value you want harcoded in `:user`

```
    INSERT INTO sessions (`user`) select user from 
    (select 0 as user from sessions where not exists(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0)) T1
```

Comment: In fact, I have tried this before IF, and it didn't work as well. IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0) INSERT INTO sessions (user) VALUES(0) causes 'SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0) INSERT INTO se' at line 1'.

Comment: @noober, try my edit now. I think user is a reserved word for mysql. Enclose user in `

Comment: INSERT INTO sessions (user) VALUES (0) works without `, but IF EXISTS (SELECT 1) SELECT 2 does not with the same message (1064).

Comment: The same error 1064. Maybe, because it's not a stored procedure.

Comment: @noober please, one more try ? Also, im not sure if you need to add a Limit 1

Comment: @ElVieejo Thank you a lot, it runs without errors, but doesn't insert new session into an empty table.

Comment: @noober, so, use another from table. You're reading a constant, so, it doesn't matter which one you use, you could use any table with one of more rows (example, system tables). Or better, do select User from (select :user as User) T1 where not exists(..). If this works, I will edit my answer so you can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Elvieejo's solution seems good, except looks like you'd have to use not exists going by the problem stated.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sessions WHERE user = 0 AND expired = 0)
    INSERT INTO sessions (user) VALUES(:user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO sessions (user) VALUES(:user)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, it ignores all but 'user' column. I want to insert a new row even if there are rows with the same user ID, but they all are expired (have a given value in the 'expired' column).

Comment: In other words, I cannot have a *conditional* key to use it with INSERT IGNORE.